# Error to get Traffic Estimator for adword using Google Adword API

Tags: python, soap, google-ads-api

I have to use the [Google Adword Traffic Estimator API](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService.html) to get my adword details.I think it could be possible to run in two ways.

1.[without client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-python-lib/wiki/NoClientLibrary)
2. [With client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-python/source/browse/trunk/examples/adspygoogle/adwords/v201109/optimization/estimate_keyword_traffic.py)

**When i follow without client detail part:**

it runs into issue.

```
 gridlex@gridlex-laptop:~/Documents$ wsdl2py --url=https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201109/TrafficEstimatorService?wsdl --output- dir=.
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ZSI/resolvers.py:7: DeprecationWarning: the   multifile module has been deprecated since Python 2.5
import multifile, mimetools, urllib
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ZSI/wstools/Utility.py:143: DeprecationWarning: socket.ssl() is deprecated.  Use ssl.wrap_socket() instead.
 ssl = socket.ssl(realsock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ZSI/wstools/Utility.py:144: DeprecationWarning:  FakeSocket is deprecated, and won't be in 3.x.  Use the result of ssl.wrap_socket() directly  instead.
 self.sock = httplib.FakeSocket(sock, ssl)
 Error loading   https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201109/TrafficEstimatorService?wsdl: 
sendall
```

**When i follow using the client library**

It askes valid client id.Here i don't know How to get my valid client id?
This is my configuration file "adwords_api_python_15.0.6/adwords_api_auth.pkl"

```
  (dp0
  S'clientCustomerId'
  p1
  S'436-059-9693'
  p2
 sS'developerToken'
 p3
 S'marketing@gridlex.com++USD'
 p4
 sS'clientEmail'
 p5
 S''
 p6
 sS'userAgent'
 p7
 S'AwApi-Python-15.0.6|GoogleTest'
 p8
 sS'password'
 p9
 S'mypassword'
p10
sS'email'
p11
S'marketing@gridlex.com'
p12
s.
```

Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get your client ID by logging into your adWords account. It is displayed on the top right corner.

Comment: yeah I tried.But it shows the same error like Invalid ID. i think have to activate MCC account sort of.Is it primary? how about that?